Pick out the time expression:
A grammar exercise on  "time expression" in Burlington app (British textbook publisher) has the following activity:

The child had been crying for long, before she picked him up..
(Pick out the time expression in the sentence given.).
A) before
B) picked
C) for long

What do you mean by "time expression"?
Which is the right answer?
Does the question have more than one right answer?
Edit #1.
There were concerns raised in the comments section about the usage of "crying for long" in the sentence.
Since 1950, Ngram has documented the usage of both "crying for long" and "waiting for long." Therefore, the sentence is grammatically correct.
Here are the Ngrams for

Crying for long:
Waiting for long.

Examples taken from Ludwig Guru, The New Yorker and Washington Post

It implies a period of waiting, but the exact length of time is unspecified. For example, you could say: "I had to wait for long before I got the answer I was looking for".
AI feedback courtesy of Ludwig Guru

When enlisted men had to wait for long, they usually became a little raucous and horsed around, grab-assing — it was one of their privileges.
The New Yorker

The Europeans should not believe that the Islamic Republic of Iran will wait for long,"
Washington Post.



It seems like you're quoting some kind of test you've encountered. Can you tell more about it? Does it have instructions or other things that might help explain?

I mean, this seems like a flawed test question in which we can only guess at the best answer. If you made it up, let's work with a better made-up scenario. If you encountered it or something like it, please tell more about what you found. "Time indicator word" is not an official or terribly common phrase. Also, the example sentence has some issues that aren't totally idiomatic.

If it helps, my guess is that long is the expected answer. It clearly describes a length of time. Before could be right, but describes the order of events in the sentence, which is a different kind of timing. For is not really a time indicator to me. But as noted, this is all guesswork.

"time indicator words" is not a precise phrase and could refer to any word that has anything to do with time. That one has to choose artificially between "long" and "before" makes it a matter of opinion. The question should be closed.

The example sentence isn't grammatical. Either the word "for" should be deleted, or if you want to keep it, then it should be: "for a long time before".

@BillyKerr Are these sentences from the dictionary incorrect? Will you be away for long? Jupiter: The way we write also makes it difficult to play for long. Have you been waiting for long? The guardsman was on his back, but Jule knew he wouldn't be down for long.

No. But these aren't the same construction at all.  The words "long before" are never preceded by "for".  see google ngram viewer

The only exceptions for this rule are at the beginning of a sentence when "For" means "Because", however this is a rather archaic use of "For", and another possible exception would be where "long before" is separated by a comma, or by context. For example: She hadn't waiting for long [,] before she realised the train had been cancelled". But this is very rare without a comma. And adding a comma wouldn't work in the example sentence anyway.

It is "for long" . The next clause starts with before. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=For+long+&year_start=1800&year_end=2022&corpus=en&smoothing=3

I see you have now edited the sentence, but adding a comma does not work here. You cannot say "The child had been crying for long, before . . . ". This doesn't make sense and it's not grammatical.  It should be "The child had been crying for a long time, before . . . " or "The child had not been crying for long, before . . ." - but these mean very different things - precisely the opposite.

@BillyKerr "crying for long" is correct grammar whether you like it or not.

@JamesMathai - Nobody said "crying for long" is not correct. I take it you didn't actually bother reading my last comment, so I'm done here.

Compare these results between  "crying for a long time" and "crying for long"

You need to provide a link to the website (Burlington app) that has that question. There are a lot of rubbishy websites professing to help learners of English, written by non-native speakers. I agree the negative is needed here in order to make sense. Even saying "crying for a long time" is more commonly used than the one cited in the test/eam question.

@Mari-LouA Whenever I post something from the UK publisher (about 4-5 posts), it got negative comments. There are practical difficulties in posting the link as it isn't available to everyone. I am in agreement with the publishers that language learners should learn the time expressions as it helps them to understand the tenses. If the post is not good for the site it should be deleted.

If it's an exam question, it's a terrible one.

I don't think you would ever say this. However, you might say:


The child had been crying for a long time before she picked him up.
or
The child had not been crying for long before she picked him up.


If I had to guess, I'd say that long is the answer, because it describes the length of time that the child was crying. Before has to do with when, but doesn't designate a length of time. For definitely is not the right answer.


Are these sentences from the dictionary incorrect? Will you be away for long?
Jupiter: The way we write also makes it difficult to play for long.
Have you been waiting for long?
The guardsman was on his back, but Jule knew he wouldn't be down for long.

In such contexts, [for] long is a negative polarity lexical item. With or without the optional preposition for, you can say I wasn't there [for] long, but the non-negated version I was there [for] long is not idiomatically valid in English. That's why the OP's cited "exam question" is such a waste of time.

@FumbleFingers also in particular, the term "long before" is very very rarely preceded by "for".  It's almost non-existent, with very few valid exceptions. see google ngram viewer.  It would also be possible to say "The child had been crying long before she picked him up" (minus the "for" obviously).

@FumbleFingers Those sentences are from the dictionary.

@JamesMathai: Don't make me laugh. Any dictionary that would present The child had been crying for long, before she picked him up isn't remotely credible! You haven't provided a link to your source, but my guess it's some shoddy online "publication" put out by a non-Anglophone.

...apart from this actual ELL question, Google finds only one other instance of non-negated "had been crying for long before" on the entire Internet. And a brief glance at that is enough to confirm my initial assumption that despite having a generally (over-?)confident attitude to the use of English, the writer (Nigerian columnist Tunji Ajibade) is not a native Anglophone.

@BillyKerr: I don't think your "The child had been crying long before she picked him up" is the same construction. In that context, long validly validly attaches to and modifies following before (so for isn't even "optional"; it simply can't be included). In the context under consideration, long (with optional for) adverbially attaches backwards to preceding verb crying.

@FumbleFingers - I know, and I agree, and yes its a different construction and means something completely different, but at least it's grammatical.  The question the OP found in a test paper is basically nonsense. If he actually found it, that is ;)

I'm voting to close this question, because it's basically rubbish, and based on something which is not even grammatical.

@FumbleFingers  but my guess it's some shoddy online "publication" put out by a non-Anglophone. What a joke? This is a question from Burlington English.

I've never heard of Burlington English. But surely my comment about the only other example on the entire Internet of this construction in a non-negated context being from a non-native Anglophone should convince you it's completely non-idiomatic. What do you hope to gain by insisting otherwise?

@FumbleFingers I have put the Ngram for "crying for long" is a separate clause. "before " is the start of another clause. You can't combine both as a single phrase. I didn't know the origin. Later after all the negative comments I checked and found that it was from a British publication. Both crying for long" and  "waiting for long" are new usages.

@BillyKerr You are badly mistaken. It is not non-native Anglophone as you guys think. It's from a British publisher. "crying for long" is correct grammar. Please update.

@JamesMathai: A single instance of such a non-idiomatic construction doesn't make the usage credible - it's virtually 100% certain your cited example arises from a typo. Specifically, the omission of the word not from the perfectly natural form ...had not been crying [for] long. You simply can't use [for] long in such contexts unless it's negated.

See "for long" can only be used in negative statements from a related earlier answer. The only context I can think of where non-negated "[for] long" is valid would be in a question format: "Have you been waiting [for] long?" - where "I haven't been waiting long" is a perfectly valid response, but "I've been waiting long" isn't.

@FumbleFingers There is no typing error from my side as I have double checked in the publisher's website. There is another sentence in a dictionary: Jupiter: The way we write also makes it difficult to play for long. (Or is it for the verb "cry" only). Who knows -: Grammar rules keep changing.

@JamesMathai "There is no typing error on my side" - but publishers do make typos. Anybody can make a simple typo, even native English speakers. It probably wasn't proof-read properly. This is certainly an error, and shouldn't be included in a test or exam. Everybody has been trying to tell you so. This is not a recent change in grammar. It's an error that any native English speaker will instantly pick up on. Also note that "makes it difficult to [do something]" is a negative construction. You can't turn this into a positive "makes it easy to play for long", which is ungrammatical.

@BillyKerr Check Ludwig guru link. They have explained with a similar sentences also news items from Washington Post. **It implies a period of waiting, but the exact length of time is unspecified. For example, you could say "I had to wait for long before I got the answer I was looking for". **
https://app.ludwig.guru/s/wait+for+long

@BillyKerr: I must admit that I'm not 100% behind Prof Lawler's comment *Not very far did he hit the ball and *Not for very long did she stay in the water are both ungrammatical because they don't negate. I suppose it's possible that from the strict syntactic / linguistic position, those aren't "true negations", but to me they just sound a bit "awkward" rather than "invalid".

"I had to wait for long before I got the answer I was looking for" is NOT grammatical. For goodness sake. Also your link is behind a login. Also I don't care who said it was OK, it's just wrong. Full stop!

@James - I had to wait for long before I got the answer I was looking for is not valid.

Maybe other typing mistakes I have to defend if people call the post as rubbish, non grammatical . *Evidences from New Yorker and Washington Post"
When enlisted men had to wait for long, they usually became a little raucous and horsed around, grab-assing — it was one of their privileges.
The New Yorker
The Europeans should not believe that the Islamic Republic of Iran will wait for long,"
Washington Post

@JamesMathai "should not believe that . . ." makes the last quote a negative. So this one uses "for long" correctly. Also, the first quote is semantically very negative in context if you read the full paragraph, but it also contains some slang, so it's not a formal piece of writing. It's still technically ungrammatical though. Again, perhaps a proof reading issue? You can find examples mistakes everywhere, but it still doesn't make it grammatical. Your post is an example of terrible exam question, however this is NOT your fault. The error is the publisher's. It's their typo.

Also note the word "evidence" is an uncountable noun. So, there is no plural -s form.  If you want a plural you need to say "pieces of evidence". Isn't English fun!

@BillyKerr My OALD has the plural evidences. But you would end up saying,  "Also I don't care who said it was OK, it's just wrong. Full stop!"

@JamesMathai Note also that most of the examples of "evidences" seem to come from the field of Christian theology/apologetics, also some scientific and legal examples exist.  So, it's basically limited to specialist fields of study/technical jargon. However, if you use it in everyday English it will mark you out as a non-native English speaker.
